# Telethon блокировка бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

1. Как заблокировать телеграм бота с помощью библиотеки `telethon`?
2. Как удалить его из списка каналов?

Когда пробую через `client(functions.channels.LeaveChannelRequest(bot_title))` - выдаёт ошибку.